# No windows identity for DOMAIN\USER in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, claims-based-auth

There is a SharePoint 2016 production farm without issues. I built a new SharePoint 2016 DR farm using same service accounts and have run into this problem where I am unable to access user profile using C# or `SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` JavaScript method.

In both cases I am getting following error in logs:

> No windows identity for DOMAIN\USER

In above error domain and user contain actual values for e.g. `MyDomain\MyFirstName`. It is happening with all users. User Profile Service is running and syncing on both environments.
Claims to Windows service is running on both environments using same service account which has following permissions.

- Adjust memory quotas for a process
- Log on as a batch job
- Log on as a service
- Replace a process level token
- Impersonate a client after authentication

As you can see all settings are exactly same on both environments, yet DR has this problem while on production it is working fine.

How to fix this issue?